# Will Business Catalyst accept categories, tags via the API

Tags: business-catalyst

I'm trying to submit blog posts into Adobe Business Catalyst using the MetaWeblogAPI. They seem to only barely support this but I am managing to create posts, but it seems to discard any categories provided in the service call, and there's no apparent way to provide tags.

I'm using PHP and Zend Framework, example submission:

```
$endpoint = "https://mydomain.businesscatalyst.com/MetaWeblogAPI.ashx";
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client($endpoint);

$post = new stdClass();
$post->dateCreated = new DateTime();
$post->title       = "A test post";
$post->description = "Test content";
$post->categories  = array('Solutions');

$params = array(
    'blogid'        => "my-blog-id",
    'username'      => "me@mydomain.com",
    'password'      => "password",
    'post'          => $post,
    'publish'       => true
);

$postId = $client->call('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
```

This works, returning a Post ID and appearing within the blog on the site. However the Post is not linked to any categories even through the 'Solutions' category provided was pre-existing within the blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So through trial and error, I'm accepting that the answer is a simple 'no' - there is no support for categories or tags in the BC API.